# How to highlight ivy candidates in the manner of hl-line?

Tags: swiper, ivy

Coming from `helm`, I am giving `swiper` and `ivy-mode` a shot.

I'm looking for a way to highlight candidates in the way `hl-line-mode` does: full width background.

[image: hl-line]

Comment: Is your issue that the entire line is not highlighted but only the text part of the line?

Comment: Yes exactly. I don't really know how `hl-line` works, but it looks like it uses something else than `:background whatever`.

Comment: It seems like there isn't a very easy way to do this other than looking through the hl-line source code and adding that to highlight the current match in swiper. Maybe you can create an issue on the swiper github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want:

```
(setq ivy-format-function 'ivy-format-function-line)
```

Comment: I added a gif to best demonstrate what I am referring to. See how `hl-line` highlight current line (where point is), as opposed to how `swiper` highlight current candidate. I am unable to reproduce `hl-line`'s appearance with `(set-face-attribute 'ivy-current-match nil :background foo)`.

Comment: Nevermind, got it to work with latest `swiper`. Thanks :)